# How can I pass integers read from Text file into struct function?

Tags: c, function, file, struct

I want to pass a txt file of integers into the smallest_xcoord struct. I am trying to get the convex hull. My issue is, I keep getting an error when trying. How can i pass integers read from text file into my struct function? I have not included my struct Point but that stores an int x; and int y; (for the convex hull points).

````
    ```
    //GLOBAL Variable
    static int integers[100000];

    int load_integers(const char* filename)
    {
      //int integers[100000];

      FILE *fp = NULL;
      int value;
      int i = -1;

      if ((fp= fopen (filename, "r"))==NULL)
      {
        return -1;
      }

      while (fscanf (fp, "%u", &value)&& !feof(fp) && ++i <100000)
      {
         integers[i] = value;
      }
      fclose(fp);

      return i+1;
    }

    struct Point smallest_xCoord (struct Point points, int numPoints)
    {
       struct Point points[];

       struct Point minX_point = points[0];
       int i;

       for(i=1;i<numPoints;i++)
       {
         if ((points[i].x) < (minX_point.x))
         {
            minX_point = points[i];
         }
         else if (points[i].x == minX_point.x)
         {
            if (points[i].y < minX_point.y)
            {
               minX_point=points[i];
            }
         }
    }
      return minX_point;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

       int num_ints=0;

       if (argc <2)
       {
         fprintf(stderr, "%s <file>\n",argv[0]);
         return -1;
       }

       if ((num_ints = load_integers(argv[1])) <=0)
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from file: %s\n",argv[1]);
          return -1;
       }

       smallest_xCoord(integers, num_ints);

       return 0;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: `while (fscanf (fp, "%u", &value)&& !feof(fp) && ++i <100000)` better as `while (fscanf (fp, "%u", &value) == 1 && i + 1 <100000)` then increment in `integers[i++] = value;` Also initialize `int i = 0;` Are you skipping the 1st point on purpose in `for(i=1;i<numPoints;i++)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smallest_xCoord(integers, num_ints);

First, you can't pass an integer data type to a "Point" data type parameter.
Second, you can't pass an array integer data type to a single Point parameter.

struct Point smallest_xCoord (struct Point points, int numPoints)
    {
       struct Point points[];

Third, you can't create a new variable inside of x_Coord with similar name to its parameter because you're re-declaring it.

If you want to pass in an array as a paramater, you gotta use a pointer (*) before its name. For the smallest_xCoord function to work, you need to specify which member of the Point struct you want to compare or assign it to. My suggestion to you is, you probably need to change that global int array variable to a global Point array variable and load it with value from your file which I assume, should contain values for x and y coordinates so that you can compare the loaded global Point array to the one you're providing. Then, change the parameter of smallest_xCoord to "struct Point *points" or "struct Point points[]" since you are passing an array to be compared.